# A problem about the etymology of “expiate”

Tags: etymology

How to explain the etymology of the word “expiate”? I found that ex means “out, for” and piate means “pious”. But I dont see how they combine to mean “to atone for”

Comment: Whoever wrote the Oxford English Dictionary entry on this one (the basis of the answer here) was skirting the truth at best. For he actually wrote the definition of "propitiation" (i.e., to satisfy the penalty requiring God's wrathful response and thus to avert that wrath). As you delineate, "ex" means "out". Here, theologically, it means to remove our sins as far from us as the east is from the west. The 2 goats on Yom Kippur symbolized the twin aspects.

Comment: The Goat of Propitiation died to satisfy the demands of the broken law (and thus its blood was sprinkled on the "mercy seat"-hilasterion, hilasmos, which was the Greek word used for "propitiation" in Romans 3:25, Heb. 7:14, 1 Jn. 2:2, 4:10). The Goat of Expiation had the sins of the people confessed over it, and was then released in the wilderness to show that the sins of the people were removed far from them.

Answer (score 3):

The "ex-" element in *expiate* as a prefix does not only mean "out of, from, for". It also could mean "former, previous", as in "*ex-girlfriend*", and "not, without", and in some cases, "completely", the last of which seems to be the case here.

[Etymology online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/expiation?ref=etymonline_crossreference)'s entry for **expiation** indicates

> via Middle French expiation or directly from Latin *expiationem* (nominative *expiatio*) "satisfaction, atonement," noun of action from past participle stem of *expiare* "make amends for, atone for; purge by sacrifice, make good," **from ex- "completely" + piare "propitiate, appease," from pius "faithful, loyal, devout"**.

So it makes sense to see **expiate** as *atone completely for* (because of piety).

It should also be noted that the word has not had this sole meaning since it entered the English language in the 15th century. Shakespeare, for example, used this word to convey a somewhat different meaning:

> My glass shall not persuade me I am old,
>
> So long as youth and thou are of one date;
>
> But when in thee time's furrows I behold,
>
> Then look I death my days should **expiate**. ([Sonnet 22](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sonnets/22.html))

Here its meaning is along the lines of "end" or "expire". What's intriguing is you could see this old meaning as employing a different meaning of "ex-": "without" or "out" (out of existence).